# Reading specific sheet in read_excel in Shiny app

Tags: shiny

I am creating a Shiny app that takes an Excel file and automatically manipulates the data. I want the user to be input the name of the specific Excel ***sheet*** that they want to look at. I'm having trouble finding a way to use textInput in the UI and input$filesheet in the Server for this. My code may help make more sense of this issue:

UI

```
fileInput('file1', 'Insert File',
            accept = c(".xlsx"),
textInput('file1sheet','Name of Sheet (Case-Sensitive)')
```

SERVER

```
inFile1 <- input$file1
sheetname1 <- input$file1sheet
df1 <- read_excel(inFile1$datapath,sheet = sheetname1)
```

The issue is that sheetname1 doesn't seem to work as read_excel doesn't recognize it as a correct expression. I have tried a few things, including ShQuote and as.character. If anybody has a solution for this, that would be awesome!

Thanks!

Stefan

Comment: you should provide a full reproducible example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have tried to understand what you were looking for and I was not able to reproduce your error. But maybe you can have a look at the following code to see where your code fails. The following app lets the user select an .xlsx file, then retrieves the sheets names before displaying the corresponding table.

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput('file1', 'Insert File', accept = c(".xlsx")),
  textInput('file1sheet','Name of Sheet (Case-Sensitive)'),
  tableOutput("value")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  sheets_name <- reactive({
    if (!is.null(input$file1)) {
      return(excel_sheets(path = input$file1$datapath))  
    } else {
      return(NULL)
    }
  })

  output$value <- renderTable({
    if (!is.null(input$file1) && 
        (input$file1sheet %in% sheets_name())) {
      return(read_excel(input$file1$datapath, 
                        sheet = input$file1sheet))
    } else {
      return(NULL)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```